# Join two arrays and find duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, concatenation

How may I find in two (or more) arrays duplicates and show it ?

I want to use filter, It's a good idea to use it ?

This is what I tried **:**

```
let monday = ["task1", "task2", "task3", "task4", "taks5", "task6", "taks7"];
let tuesday = ["task2", "task3", "task4", "task5", "taks6"];
let wendesday = ["task7", "task8", "task9", "task10", "taks11", "task12"];

const takePastList = monday

.concat(tuesday)
    .join(" ")
    .filter((task, index) => index !== monday.indexOf(task));
```

In above solution, `concat` works but `filter` not.

Find how to fix it and understand how to use filter or other method to find duplicate when I work on many arrays with many methods.

Comment: What are you looking to get as output?

Comment: If your goal is to return a list of duplicates, you would do something like:  `const s = new Set(monday); const result = tuesday.filter(x => s.has(x))`. This would return a list of items in Tuesday which are in Monday.

Comment: You have TYPO in the array elements, is it by your intention? `TASK` vs `TAKS`

Comment: Yes thanks, I didn't know how to add this ( the simillar solutions) without if to this function.

Comment: Output. To have the same tasks which are duplicate in all arrays (not achived during all days). To show it for user.

Comment: please be specific with your example output - what should the value of `takePastList` be when the script is done? `"task1"`? `["task4"]`? `["task7", "task11"]`? etc

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones all duplicates ("task1", "task8", "task9", "task10", "task11",
  "task12", ...) and then ask user, which task do you want to continue becouse are not achived for 7 days (!), all, which. This is main goal for the script

Comment: @codegrafo ... besides the typos (e.g. compare `"taks5"` against `"task5"`) which the OP already got pointed to now regarding the OP's above comment ... the task numbers `8`, `9`, `10`, `11`, `12` are the ones which actually are not duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to keep and display duplicated values, you were on the right lines but made a mistake using .join(" ").

`.join()` is an `array method` that returns a `string` of the array elements joined together into a `string` variable.

You are then trying to apply your `.filter` (an `array method`) to a `string`.

If you delete the `.join(" ")` step, your routine works to return an array holding the values that were present in both the two `.concat`enated arrays.

The resulting array can be processed again to add the third array as demonstrated in this two-step snippet (based on your `.map` function).

```js
let monday = ["task1", "task2", "task3", "task4", "taks5", "task6", "taks7"];
let tuesday = ["task2", "task3", "task4", "task5", "taks6"];
let wednesday = ["task7", "task8", "task9", "task10", "taks11", "task12"];

const takePastList = monday


.concat(tuesday)
.filter((task, index) => index !== monday.indexOf(task));

const nextAr = takePastList.concat(wednesday).filter((task, index) => index !== takePastList.indexOf(task));

console.log(takePastList);
```

(Wednesday spelling corrected)

In practice you might want to build a function that can be called repeatedly, or recursively, to include further arrays for comparison. There is a caveat - if there was an element in the first array that is not present in the second, it will not be in the output of the first cycle and so will not be detected as a duplicate if the third array is compared to the output of the first two procedure. It depends what you need whether this is a problem.

Basically, your `.map` function was fine, but it should not have been applied to a `string`

Comment: what method should I use to string?

Comment: You can apply .join(" ") to the final array to make a string as you did in your example. Once it's a string, you can't use map on it without first turning it back into an array using the `string` method `.split(" ")` which will separate the space-seprated 'words' into elements of a new array.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this might suits your needs

```
let monday = ["task1", "task2", "task3", "task4", "taks5", "task6", "taks7"];
let tuesday = ["task2", "task3", "task4", "task5", "taks6"];
let wendesday = ["task7", "task8", "task9", "task10", "taks11", "task12"];

//solution
let allTasks = monday.concat(tuesday, wendesday);
let duplicates = allTasks.filter((item, index) => allTasks.indexOf(item) !== index);
console.log(duplicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution if you are looking for duplicates.

```js
    let monday = ["task1", "task2", "task3", "task4", "task5", "task6", "task7"];
    let tuesday = ["task2", "task3", "task4", "task5", "task6"];
    let wendesday = ["task7", "task8", "task9", "task10", "task11", "task12"];

    const takePastList = monday
      .concat(tuesday);
    const duplicates =  takePastList.filter((item, index) => index !== takePastList.indexOf(item));

    console.log(duplicates)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this requirement with a single line of code by using [`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax along with [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter),
[`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`Array.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) methods.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let monday = ["task1", "task2", "task3", "task4", "taks5", "task6", "taks7"];
let tuesday = ["task2", "task3", "task4", "task5", "taks6"];
let wendesday = ["task7", "task8", "task9", "task10", "taks11", "task12"];

const duplicateItemsArr = [...monday, ...tuesday, ...wendesday].filter((item, index, arr) => arr.indexOf(item) !== arr.lastIndexOf(item));

console.log(duplicateItemsArr);
```

Comment: Ha, not always it will be so clear, (first and last Item is not duplicated) but its very interesting solution.

Comment: @codegrafo It will work fine in any scenarios. You can test it with some other examples and confirm if is there any changes required.